# How to get platform packages source code of specific release?

Tags: android, android-source

How to get platform packages source code of specific release?
I want https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts from android 4.0.4 (ICS_MR1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get platform packages source code of specific release?

Check out the source code associated with the desired tag or branch. In this case, I would imagine that you are looking for https://github.com/android/platform_packages_apps_contacts/tree/ics-mr1-release.

Comment: Thank you. I should have known it was somewhere in commits.